# How to query ManagedBy property of ADComputer in a Foreach loop?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to generate a list of computers owned by a particular PDL and I'm encountering some syntax issues:

```
$group = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "pdl" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
Foreach($item in $group) { Get-ADComputer -Filter "ManagedBy -eq "$item"" -Property managedby | Select Name }
```

The second part is based on another code snippet that I found elsewhere (I think on StackOverflow as well) which worked just fine:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "ManagedBy -eq 'CN=user@company.com,OU=US,OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=com'" -Property ManagedBy
```

But the difference is I could use '' in this one, but adding in $item prevents me from using that.

The syntax error I get back with the first snippet:

```
Get-ADComputer : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'CN=user@company.com,OU=US,OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=com'.
At D:\Documents\Scripts\uatgroup.ps1:2 char:31
+ Foreach($item in $UATgroup) { Get-ADComputer -Filter "ManagedBy -eq "$item"" -Pr ...
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
```

Anyone know a way to fix the syntax here?  Or an alternate method of running this?

Comment: Use single-quotes or escape your innermost double-quotes

Comment: Thanks! I thought that single quotes prevented any variables from working, but it looks like this works!  I'll go back and re-read PS syntax documentation to get a better understanding.

Comment: When `'` is encountered *inside* a double-quoted string, it's just treated as a character like any other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
"ManagedBy -eq "$item""
```

Is parsed as three separate strings. Only the first one (`ManagedBy -eq`) will be bound to the `-Filter` parameter, the rest will be treated as separate tokens, causing PowerShell to complain that you can't just leave the string `CN=...` there in the middle of everything.

You can either use single-quotes inside the double-quoted string, to avoid terminating the string early:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "ManagedBy -eq '$item'"
```

Escape the inline double-quotes with a backtick ( `` ` `` ):

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "ManagedBy -eq `"$item`""
```

Or escape them by doubling them:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "ManagedBy -eq ""$item"""
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought that single quotes prevented any variables from working, but it looks like this works!  I'll go back and re-read PS syntax documentation to get a better understanding.
Wish I could vote on this, but it looks like I'm too new :(

Comment: Inside the already double-quoted string, the single-quote is just another character, but otherwise you would have been correct yes. If you feel the answer sufficiently addressed your question, tick the Accept sign under the voting arrows

Comment: Thanks!  I'm usually a lurker on StackOverflow and this is my first time asking a question, so I really appreciate the help! :)